# nvidia-smi not work in zbook studio g8 under ubuntu/linux

Tags: nvidia, hp, cuda, gpu

When I run `nvidia-smi`, it always shows:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I have tried Popos, manjaro, ubuntu 22.04, none of them works. The GPU is only available in Windows, which is bad.

How can I solve it?

I expect to see the real-time memory usage for the GPU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cuda: NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225886/cuda-nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driv)

Comment: @karel I've spent 7 days to solve this problem, you think the answer could get found online???

Comment: @karel This is a stupid `bios bug` which can't get solved easily in software level: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-20-04-hp-zbook-studio-g8-rtx3080-ti/221835/7#:~:text=Apr%2020-,This%20was%20a%20bios%20bug,-on%20the%20zbook

Comment: I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

### 1. Install a special ubuntu system starting from HP website

https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-studio-15.6-inch-g8-mobile-workstation-pc/2100677682

> Choose ubuntu, download the iso file, put it into a usb by using `Balena Etcher`, flush it into your laptop

### 2. After you get into the ubuntu20.04 system

You could use `nvidia-smi` to check the GPU memory.

### 3. Install tensorflow by using `anaconda`

Tensorflow has a tutorial in here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

It's something like this:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.8.0
python3 -m pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163 tensorflow==2.12.*
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
source $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
# Verify install:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

### 4. Install pytorch

```bash
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

> https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Verify it:

```bash
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

## Method 2

### 1. Upgrade HP bios

You could directly use online bios update to update your bios fireware.

```
Reboot -> F2 -> Esc -> Set up WiFi -> reboot -> F10 -> update bios in a online way
```

Or you could use Windows system to do the update:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_3894564-1633733-16

### 2. Switch to `integrated graphics only mode`

In popos, you can do it in right-top-corner icon, power settings.

In ubuntu, you can do it in `nvidia-settings` -> `profile-settings` -> `use integrated graphics`

reboot

### 3. Use gcc-12

```
which gcc



# if gcc is not gcc-12, then do the following

sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc
```

### 4. Install nvidia special driver for your special gpu version

For me, it's `GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile`.

From the nvidia driver download page, you could download a file like `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.105.17.run`

https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Then you do the following:

```bash
sudo chmod 777 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.105.17.run

sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.105.17.run
```

### 5. Switch back to `nvidia graphics only mode`

reboot

Now, you should be able to use `nvidia-smi` to see the real-time gpu memory info

### 6. Install anaconda

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html#installing-on-linux

Download a file look like `Anaconda3-2023.03-Linux-x86_64.sh`

```bash
sudo chmod 777 Anaconda3-2023.03-Linux-x86_64.sh

sudo ./Anaconda3-2023.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

### 7. Install cuda by using conda

Now, open a new terminal window

Then, try to install tensorflow by using script from tensorflow official documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.8.0

python3 -m pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163 tensorflow==2.12.*

mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d

echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh

echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh

source $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh

# Verify install:

python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

### 8. Done

author: @yingshaoxo

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question; the question mentions many off-topic OSes and one Ubuntu release; which isn't 20.04 that is mentioned in this *answer*. For this to be a valid answer, it should match the question details (*one of question or answer needs correction*).

Comment: @guiverc Because the stupid HP doesn't provide ubuntu22.04, it only provides 20.04.

Comment: Why not change the question to be about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS then, given that's what your answer relates to. The question & answer need to match, and currently this doesn't answer the question as it assumes the question relates to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  If you tested it on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; adjust the wording to say you tested it & it works; but the answer as worded does not answer the asked question as I read it as it's written for a different release.

Comment: @guiverc Trust me, I have tested ubuntu starting from 20.04, including 22.04.  I even tried pop_os, can you believe it?